# No sound card detected: HP EliteBook

Tags: sound

I can't seem to get any sound working on my HP Elitebook with Elementary 5.0 fresh install. Hope someone can help. Thanks.

aplay -l

```
aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...
```

pacmd list-sinks

```
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE 
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max request: 344 KiB
    max rewind: 344 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    module: 11
    properties:
        device.description = "Dummy Output"
        device.class = "abstract"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card"
```

Laptop details

```
product: HP EliteBook 820 G3 (L4Q16AV)
   product: 807C
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz
         product: HMA41GS6AFR8N-TF
      product: Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
         product: HD Graphics 520
         product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
            product: xHCI Host Controller
               product: VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
               product: HP HD Camera
            product: xHCI Host Controller
         product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
         product: Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
         product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
         product: Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
         product: Intel Corporation
            product: RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader
         product: Intel Corporation
            product: Wireless 8260
         product: Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
         product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
         product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
         product: Ethernet Connection I219-V
         product: LITEON L8H-128V2
   product: SN03044XL
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in terminal: sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel, if you recover audio, add snd-hda-intel to file /etc/modules. This will make the snd-hda-intel module load up  at boot time.

You can use: sudo sh -c 'echo "snd-hda-intel" >> /etc/modules' to do this